# add slick carousel in Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

hello I have 2 components in a template I would like in this block added a single component slick carousel

But when I do it distorts the images of the other component

```
<template v-if="isMobile">
        <vue-slick-carousel :arrows="true" :dots="true">
        <component
          :is="picture.template"
          v-for="picture in groupOne"
          :key="picture.title"
          :params="picture"
          :size="params.size"
          @click="onClick(picture)"
          />
        </vue-slick-carousel>
        <component
          :is="picture.template"
          v-for="picture in groupTwo"
          :key="picture.title"
          :params="picture"
          :size="params.size"
          @click="onClick(picture)"
        />
      </template>
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

hello i have a answer to my question i don't add a width to my slick slider

```
.slick-slider {
    max-width: 320px;
    margin: 0 auto;
```

is good